# Apt-get install -f and apt-get autoremove error

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, dependencies

I've tried to install new software on Ubuntu and it told me to use that command `apt-get install -f`, but I get back an error message and I have no idea how to fix it.

After that, I tried to use `apt-get autoremove` but again an error message.

```
apt-get install -f
```

```
Errors were encountered while processing: 
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6-dev_2.5.2-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb E:
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
apt-get autoremove
```

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcairo2-dev : Depends: libfreetype6-dev (>= 2.1.10) but it is not installed
 libfontconfig1-dev : Depends: libfreetype6-dev (>= 2.1.7) but it is not installed
 libpango1.0-dev : Depends: libfreetype6-dev but it is not installed
 libxft-dev : Depends: libfreetype6-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Command `apt-get install -f` ask me to do `autoremove` first... and `apt-get autoremove` ask me to do `install -f` correctly first.

So what am I supposed to do?

Comment: try `apt-get install -f` again.

Comment: I've try again and again... I have the same error message

Comment: Can you attempt `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` and post the output of the command?

Comment: `E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/`

Comment: I can't install anything...

Comment: That lock indicates the updater is still launched ... alt-tab  to see its running icon ... close out of it then from terminal re-issue your install cmd

Comment: Sorry, I paste the wrong error message, that the real error when I've try to install **sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev** `Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libfreetype6-dev_2.5.2-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: And how I've stay above.. I can't install anything